# Keep client's API Secret in browser and access it by JS

Tags: javascript, security

We have server side authorization, that requires every request to the server to be signed using secret key. It works fine for API purposes when communication is done server<->server.

On client<->server we use SMS authorization.

SMS is not really reliable, it's not fast enough and it costs us a lot.

*The basic idea:*
We allow user to store his secret API key in browser's local storage. It's kept there encoded with his secret password (not know by us).
When user wants to open security session, he is prompted by JS to enter his secret password. JS takes his secret API key from local storeage, decodes it with that password and uses to sign verification request. On server side we know secret and if verification request signed with correct key, we open security session.

This way user actually authorises particular browser on particular machine to open security session (with the use of additional secret password).

*The question:*
How safe is it to keep encoded secret API key in browser's local storage? How safe is it to decode it with client's password by JS?

Comment: Safe from what?  A browser's local storage is only as safe as anything else on a user's hard drive.  It should not be accessible to javascript in the browser on other sites, but once outside the browser, it's just in a file somewhere on the hard drive.  If it's encrypted with a user-supplied password that is itself not stored, then you're in even better shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Two-factor authentication provides unambiguous identification of users
>   by means of the combination of two different components.

Your solution is not related to two factor authentication. Because two factor can secure your client when username/password stolen. For example one of your client's computer infected by malware and this malware have ability to sniff keyboard actions ( which is feature almost all malwares). In your solution anyone can easily login even if you asking password again and again.

Using mobile phones as second factor authentication is against scenario that I described above.

Also storing sensitive information on client side is always bad idea even if you have a chance to encrypt it. (Further info : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet) Another thing is your encryption algorithms is developed without any issue.

I suggest you to use Google Authenticator without paying single dollar. I think almost all of your client have smart phone and they can easily use google authenticator app for two factor.

Comment: Thanks for recommendations an answer!